# Will a strong tournament still be a strong tounament after removing a vertex from it?

Tags: graph-theory

I was trying to prove a theorem in a new way other than the one our doctor gave us, but there is a step that I am not sure of.

If $G$ is a strong tournament is there a vertex that can be removed from the graph for the graph to still be a strong tournament?

I think its not true for ANY vertex, but can we find 1? Or more than 1? And is there a condition for that?

Comment: Are you talking about that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory) ? Or maybe the Strong part add something. If you have a tournament, removing any vertex will give you a tournament for sure.

Comment: It's not true for a strong tournament with $3$ vertices, but it's true for any strong tournament on more than $3$ vertices. It's usually stated this way: If $G$ is a strong tournament of order $n$, then $G$ contains a directed cycle of length $k$ for every integer $k$ such that $3\le k\le n$.

Comment: Hint: Induction on $k$. First, a strong tournament can't be transitive, so it contains a directed $3$-cycle. Next, a simple argument shows that, if $G$ contains a $k$ cycle, and if $k\lt n$, then $G$ contains a $k+1$-cycle. Keep getting longer and longer cycles till you find a directed cycle $C$ of length $n-1$. Remove the vertex $v\in V(G)\setminus V(C)$.